# Signal Processing on Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory, clustering

I would like to observe how a kernel looks in the node domain, at node $i$. I am given the Fourier basis $\mathbf{U}$, a filter kernel $\hat{g}(\lambda)$, and a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $\mathbf\Lambda$.

Do you know how to compute the localized kernel $T_i g \in \mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: Could you give a reference ? Although I am acquainted with signal processing on the one hand and (in a lesser way) spectral theory of graphs on the other, I don't find back in your question anything I know... Are you referencing to a kind of heat kernel ?

Comment: @JeanMarie A good reference to start is this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.0053.pdf  "The Emerging Field of Signal Processing on Graphs".

Comment: Thank you. I am going to read it.